# React Native - iOS and App Center Deployment build failed from main.jsbundle

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, deployment, visual-studio-app-center

Firstly thank you for taking the time to help me find a result. Just a bit of background on what I've done so you know what angles I've taken.

React - `"react-native": "0.62.2"`

1. I'm using App center to deploy my iOS app (this is where the issue lies),
2. I have three schemes for iOS Dev, Beta, Prod (each building fine in xCode),
3. I'm using Code push as well,
4. App has been on Test flight working fine for a week

I encountered a build issue "no URL bundle present" when running locally both in debug and in release. However I found a solution for that here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eCs2GsWNkoo which works great. I added the `main.jsbundle` into `build phases` >>  `Copy bundle resources` as well which fixed the issue occurring during release. Archiving tests now all works.

However **My issue is** when I build the app on App Center with the `main.jsbundle` in `Copy Bundle resources` the build fails and I believe this is because App Center creates that file itself? The error I face is:

```
The following build commands failed:
    CpResource /Users/runner/work/1/s/ios/main.jsbundle /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/aLifeLived-hjrawomvzxvvvdeuplegfjyupvhr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/aLifeLived/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/A\ Life\ Lived.app/main.jsbundle
(1 failure)
```

Knowing this I then went back into xCode and **removed** `main.jsbundle` from `Copy bundle resources`, re ran the build in App Center and it builds successfully...However when it appears on test flight it crashes on startup.

I believe the cause of the crash on Test Flight is due to no `main.jsbundle` or the one that is produced through App Center if they produce one - The reason I say this is 1. I can't run the app in release locally 2. I did a manual deploy to test flight (archived in xCode, download ipa file, uploaded to App Center, deployed).

I'm stuck on what to do, can someone please help?

Thanks!

Update:

I also attempted to build with `legacy build system` however this then resulted in the below error with App Center:

```
The following build commands failed:
    Ld /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/aLifeLived-hjrawomvzxvvvdeuplegfjyupvhr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/aLifeLived/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/aLifeLived.build/Release-iphoneos/aLifeLived.build/Objects-normal/armv7/A\ Life\ Lived normal armv7
    Ld /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/aLifeLived-hjrawomvzxvvvdeuplegfjyupvhr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/aLifeLived/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/aLifeLived.build/Release-iphoneos/aLifeLived.build/Objects-normal/arm64/A\ Life\ Lived normal arm64
(2 failures)
```

Comment: Hi, did you found any solution?

Comment: @PinkiDhakad unfortunately not. I ended up reverting back to a stable branch. However check out this thread it might help you. https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter/issues/174#issuecomment-725685610